# How to get IntelliJ to warn about unsafe usages of Optional.get()

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Some not-so-careful colleagues of mine have been passing around `Optional` instances and *assuming* it's safe to call `get` on them without calling `isPresent` first.

I know... this shouldn't happen, but the type-system won't stop them!!

So, I wanted IntelliJ to do it. Is it possible to configure IntelliJ so that it will warn (or even throw a compiling error) about calling `Optional.get()` without first calling `Optional.isPresent()`?

Comment: It's kind of heavy, but you could write your own inspection and install it via a plugin? Probably an easier approach... but worst case...

Comment: Do you really mean that you expect everyone to call `Optional.isPresent()` first? That's not my understanding of the intention of `Optional`. If so, it's only the same as having to remember to do a null check, so you haven't gained anything. For example, what about uses of `Optional.map()` - in that case your inspection would identify it as a problem, but it could be perfectly safe, without having called `isPresent()` first.

Comment: I mean that `get()` must be called after a check with `isPresent()`. I didn't say anything about `map()` or any other methods.

Comment: IntelliJ already supports the equivalent concept for `@Nullable` types. So you can't call any method on a `@Nullable` unless you've checked for null first. I made this a compiling error in IntelliJ and it works perfectly. Just want the same thing for Optionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ 2016.1 supports this out-of-the-box!

By default, calling `get()` without verifying with `isPresent()` first will issue a warning, but you can go to the "Inspections" screen and set `Optiong.get() without isPresent() check` to have severity "Error" if you prefer.

Comment: Interestingly, I did not manage to get this "out-of-the-box" support. Had to do it either via inspection or sonarlint :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inspection to flag instances and show you a warning/error. This may be exclusive to ultimate.

To add a custom inspection, follow https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-custom-inspections.html, or do this:

1. Open the settings (CTRL+ALT+S) and search for Inspections.
2. In the tree, find "General" and under that, "Structural Search Inspection".
3. Under the description you'll see a severity/options panel. Next to the options press +, and add a Search Template.

To configure the inspection to your question:

1. In the search template box, add a variable followed by a method invocation, such as: $Instance$.get()
2. Click edit variables and select $Instance$ from the list.
3. In the 'Expression Constraints', add the expression type "Optional", and apply the constraint within type hierarchy.

Save your changes and run the inspection. (CTRL+Shift+Alt+I, type "Structural Search Inspection"). This should show you all instances of Optional.get().

Edit: In your question you ask if it's possible to get a compilation error. I believe this will strictly depend on how you're building your code. If you add an inspection and set the error level to 'Error', it should fail on Make/Compile but not on a 'mvn install'.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. The question is asking for an inspection that identifies uses of `Optional.get()` where the developer hasn't previously checked whether the Optional is not empty. This inspection will just identify all uses of `Optional.get()`, which isn't hugely helpful.

Comment: Fair point. I got too caught up in finding the instances of the get that I lost sight of the question. I believe there are inspections in IntelliJ which follow the same pattern that OP wants, but I dont know if it's possible to create that using the in-editor inspection creator, may need to create a plugin as @vikingsteve suggested.